# Does $\Vert T\Vert=\max\{\Vert T(x)\Vert/\Vert x\Vert:x\neq 0\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

The definition I was given is that for a bounded linear transformation $T$, $||T||=\inf\{K\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x, ||T(x)||\leq K||x||\}$. After messing around with suprema and infima for a while, I've been able to show that $||T||=\sup\{\frac{||T(x)||}{||x||}:x\neq 0\}$ and thus $||T||=\min\{K\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x, ||T(x)||\leq K||x||\}$. I was curious, however, if it is also true that $||T||=\max\{\frac{||T(x)||}{||x||}:x\neq 0\}$. In other words, must there exist $x$ such that $||T(x)||=||T||\cdot||x||$? If not, what if assume the vector spaces in question are finite dimensional? What about the case $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $n, m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Edit: I am being told that it is true for finite dimensional spaces, but not necessarily for infinite dimensional spaces. If someone could give me an explanation or proof for why it's true for the finite dimensional case, I would greatly appreciate it. Also, a counterexample in the infinite dimensional case would be appreciated as well.

Comment: On a space where the unit ball is compact, yes (and so yes for all finite dimensional spaces). Otherwise, no.

Comment: If you assume finite dimensional, then yes.

Comment: In the infinite-dimensional case, the answer isn't "no" but "not necessarily".

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm assuming you are referring to the closed unit ball. I don't see immediately why the compactness of the unit ball implies the answer is true. Is it a result of the Extreme Value Theorem?

Comment: Equivalently, $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\{\|Tx\|\}$. The $\sup$ is achieved if the unit ball is compact since norm is continuous.

Comment: @user9527 Oh, I see, since $\frac{\Vert T(x)\Vert}{\Vert x\Vert}=\Vert T(\frac{1}{\Vert x\Vert}x)\Vert$. From there, it's just the Extreme Value Theorem. So then he meant the unit sphere, not ball.

Comment: @T.Bongers user9527 was able to explain it to me. Unless I am misunderstanding, your comment also appears to be implying that all finite dimensional spaces have a compact unit sphere. However $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, but does have a compact unit sphere.